# How to parse huge json data combiling multi level array by java

Tags: java, json, parsing

I am trying to parse huge JSON data. I can't give the JSON content here in this question. But you can see actual data at this link:-

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1p3lfaQ_k3C9DB3qA3W72IGiefwLUhCzm/view

I know there popular libraries like GSON and Jackson. I tired GSON as:-

```
    JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
    JsonElement element = jsonParser.parse(line); // line contains all json data
```

But JsonElement has no suitable method to get data by json key.

My intentions is to parse the data which is a array in the json data. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JsonElement` is the parent class for all nodes that the GSON parser returns. In your case the root node is a `JsonObject`, so it's safe to cast the element to that or use the convenience accessor `getAsJsonObject`.

`JsonObject` has the API you need for field access, and `JsonArray` has the API for array access:

```
JsonElement root = new JsonParser()
    .parse(new FileReader("data.json"));

JsonArray data = root.getAsJsonObject()
    .getAsJsonObject("dataset_data")
    .getAsJsonArray("data");

System.out.println(data.size());
```

Comment: It works if I have the json data saved into the file as data.json. But the actual data is coming from a URL.   URL url = new URL("https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/EOD/AAPL.json?api_key=s2zrK5rk1-_bu5cP6Q2d");
        URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
        String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
JsonElement root = new JsonParser().parse(line);

Comment: Don't read the json into a `String` first; just call `JsonElement root = new JsonParser().parse(inputStreamReader);` directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple json library

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20180130</version>
</dependency>
```

It has user friendly interface that you are require if I understood you correctly like this

```
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject("jsoncontent");
        JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("arraykey");
        Integer i=obj.getInt("someintegerfield");
        JSONObject aob = obj.getJSONObject("anotherobject");
```